# How To Execute Non-Runnable jar from Bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, jar

I am attempting to create bat file to execute my project.

Below is my project Environment

1. jdk [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin]
2. myapp.jar [D:\app\main\myapp.jar]  -> non runnable jar & contains com & META-INF folders
3. third parties libraries [D:\app\lib\ojdbc6.jar and etc]
4. resource files [D:\app\resources\myapp.properties]
5. scripts [D:\scripts\StartMyApp.bat]

i tried many ways, but cannot achieve it.

How to write bat file for this. Kindly help really i am struggling.

Comment: `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7\bin\java.exe" -cp "D:\app\main\myapp.jar";"D:\app\lib\ojdbc6.jar" main.Main [some arguments]`  ? As for the properties file it should be placed in a relative path where the program will search for it.

Comment: @npocmaka I think this could be an answer couldn't it?

Comment: @npocmaka, why using `call` for an executable?